# jQuery pass data from click event to doubleclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

Since I've tried and not succeeded many times I figure it's time to ask. I would like have several elements on the screen on which the user can click.  Once the user decides to double click somewhere on the body I would like to `console.log` the text elements of the array.
This isn't nearly as intuitive as I thought it was going to be. The following example isn't all that practical, just curious why I can't get it to work.

EDIT: I would like to NOT use a global variable.

Fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vkqbf/)

Comment: Maybe making the array global

Comment: Declare the textArray outside the scope of the first click function.

Comment: @arturo I would prefer to do this without using global variables.

Comment: I like how `getTestClassData($(this))` is more characters than `$(this).hasClass('test')` :)

Comment: The variable doesn't have to be global, but it **does** have to be defined outside the scope of the click handler. Currently, every execution of the handler creates a new instance of the array.

Comment: @JasonP strictly playing around.  This was just an exercise to learn not to use global variables and send data between functions.

Comment: @JasonP so just declare the array inside of the document.ready function?  What if I had two separate javascript files, how would I share data between them (maybe that needs to be its own question).

Comment: If you want to share across scripts, then _something_ needs to be global.. You might try the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) to have a global object that exposes only the functionality you want exposed.

Comment: Something new to read about, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to alter the scope of the array `textArray` so that your function `ferryArray()` can access it and loop over.

Here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vkqbf/1/).

Comment: I should have specified in the question, but how can this be done without using global variables?

Comment: `textArray` should be accessible to the function which loops over. It doesnt need to be global.